# How to filter rows in csv file based on column string

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to iterate through a list in a csv file to find rows where the last column contains stock ticker symbols to find a specific symbol and then write the that row to a new csv file. Not sure what is wrong. The csv file contains daily stock quotes.

```
def filter_csv():
    import csv
    with open('SP_comb_with_header.csv','r') as fin:
        with open ('SP_filtered.csv','w') as fout:
            writer = csv.writer(fout)            
            for row in csv.reader(fin):
                if fin['Ticker'] == "AAPL":
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: *"Not sure what is wrong"* Then how do you expect us to tell you? You don't currently have a question that can be answered, maybe have a read through [ask]

Comment: Your question is in danger of being closed if you do not improve it. Please add a few lines from your input CSV file and the traceback you see when you run your code.

Answer (score 3):

You should normally open your files in binary mode (see the [usage example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)) if you are using the CSV library (this assumes you are using Python 2.x). The standard reader will give you each row as a list, so the last column would be `row[-1]`.

```
import csv

def filter_csv():
    with open('SP_comb_with_header.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('SP_filtered.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

        for row in csv_input:
            if row[-1] == "AAPL":
                csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access columns using their header names, you need a [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```
import csv

def filter_csv():
    symbols = set(['AAPL', 'GOOGL'])
    with open('SP_comb_with_header.csv') as csv_in:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_in)
        with open('SP_filtered.csv', 'w') as csv_out:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, reader.fieldnames)
            for row in reader:
                if row['Ticker'] in symbols:
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

Note that if you want to write rows from a `csv.DictReader` to another CSV file, you can use a [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) as shown above. This solution uses a `set` for faster look-ups.